# Celery results not updating after dockerization

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I'm currently putting my Django app on Docker. I successfully dockerized Django, gunicorn, nginx and Celery, however when I run a Celery task, even though it's executed (displayed in the logs), the results are not stored to my database.

That worked before dockerizing everything so that probably comes from my docker configurations, but I didn't manage to find which part was incorrect/incomplete.

Also, I'm using the default sqlite3 Django database as I don't need to store a huge amount of data.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - db:/db.sqlite3
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    env_file:
      - env
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A main worker -P eventlet -c 100 -l INFO
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
      - django_gunicorn
    volumes:
      - db:/db.sqlite3

volumes:
  db:
  static:
  media:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBEFFERED = 1 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./src /app

WORKDIR /app
```

**celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')

app = Celery('main', backend='django-db')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Maybe it's because I'm using sqlite3 ? I saw everyone using PostgreSQL during my search for a solution. Should I switch to a PostgreSQL ? Or else, what should I change in order to get my tasks results in my database ?

EDIT : **settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]


#CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    'fontawesomefree',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'scripts.apps.ScriptsConfig',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# Media files (scripts, results)

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

MEDIA_URL = 'scripts/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Crispy with Bootstrap

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap5'

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq3:5672/"
```

Comment: are you talking about Celery backend results? because I don't see that you configured `backend` for `Celery`..

Comment: Yes indeed, but that's not the issue, I've just been trying several things and one of them was defining the backend in the `settings.py` file and I forgot to replace it before writing the question.

Comment: can you share the `settings.py` file?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the problem, but you are using sqlite database, which is saved as file in your project. Maybe celery worker does not have access to original database? Maybe try to change it to postgresql?

Comment: I've thought about it, but wanted to have some insight on it by posting this question. I guess I'll try postreSQL and see what I get.

Comment: Using a network-accessible database, and avoiding the complexities of Docker file sharing, definitely seems like a good approach.